# How to use JWT Tokens for Spring boot Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am very new to Spring boot security JWT tokens please give me suggestions on my requirement.
I want to use JWT tokens for Spring boot web application. Means I have rest controllers to supply data to frontend the frontend will request data from Rest Controller. Here the token exchange comes my requirement is User login once in the application and he got token no problem, here the token expiry time is 30 minutes. Here is the problem the user contentiously working on the application after 30 minutes the page expired and asking for new token but in normal web applications if user continuously working the session time automatically refreshed. I know token based authentication is stateless but please help me how to achieve this with auto refresh token like session.

Comment: Add the token in the header for every request from the front end and handle this from the server using interceptor.

Comment: Can you please provide example

Comment: What is your front end technology? Are you using ajax calls?

Comment: Yes we are using Bootstrap and JQUery Ajax

Comment: You have to implement refresh token concept whenever the token is expired. Check this link
https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-security-refresh-token/